# How to solve this kind of differential equation directly?

Tags: differential-equations

Given $f^{\prime}\left(e^{x}\right)=x e^{-x}$, $f(1)=0$, I want to find the expression of $f(x)$ (the answer is $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}(\ln x)^{2}$):

```
DSolve[{f'[E^x] == x*E^-x, f[1] == 0}, f[x], x]
```

But the above code cannot solve this problem, I wonder if we can solve this kind of differential equation directly.

**Other examples for testing:**

The answer to the example $f^{\prime}(\cos x+2)=\sin ^{2} x+\tan ^{2} x$ is $f(x)=-\frac{1}{x-2}-\frac{1}{3}(x-2)^{3}+C$.

```
DSolve[f'[Cos[x] + 2] == Sin[x]^2 + Tan[x]^2, f[x], x]
```

Comment: ```DSolve::litarg: To avoid possible ambiguity, the arguments of the dependent variable in `1` should literally match the independent variables.```

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ Can you write a custom function to handle this kind of problem?

Comment: I have tested, make it sure that `f'` acts on a `Symbol`. To that end one needs to find the inverse function. But I worry it that inverse functions are not always available.

Answer (score 3):

First we reduce the equation to the normal form $$f(x) = \text{expression}$$ so, in the case

$$
f^{\prime}(\cos x+2)=\sin ^{2} x+\tan ^{2} x
$$

we proceed as follows:

$$
y = \cos x+2\Rightarrow \sin ^{2} x+\tan ^{2} x = 1-(y-2)^2 +\frac{1-(y-2)^2}{(y-2)^2}
$$

and now integrating $f'(y)$ ...

```
Integrate[1 - (y - 2)^2 + (1 - (y - 2)^2)/(y - 2)^2, y] // FullSimplify
```

or

```
DSolve[f'[y] == 1 - (y - 2)^2 + (1 - (y - 2)^2)/(y - 2)^2, f, y]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I hope you can write a simple and general code to solve this kind of problem.

Answer (score 2):

The given set of equations is

′(exp(x))=exp(−), (1)=0

since exp(-x) is nonzero on Reals multiplied with the inverse on both sides of the equation. The multiplicative inverse is exp(x).

′(exp(x))=exp(−)    !  *exp(x) on both sides equally

exp()′(xp())=, (1)=0

That is on the left-hand side the basis for identifying the chain rule.

```
D[f[Exp[x]], x]
___
E^x Derivative[1][f][E^x]
```

So to go back from the form in which Your differential equation is given to the basic form multiply with E^x on both sides of the equation. Use the chain rule and substitute. y=E^x

```
DSolve[{F'[y] == Log[y], F[e^1] == 0}, F[y], y]
```

---

```
{{F[y] -> - y + y Log[y]}}
```

This solves the problem with mathematical weapons but does not match the required result.

```
f[E^x]=F[y]=-E^x+E^x Log[E^x]
```

IF x>0 then the functions chain can be on Reals simplied to give the desired right hand side of the given equation:

```
D[-E^x + E^x Log[E^x], x]
___
E^x Log[E^x]
```

f is essentially the `Log` function.

Same for the next question part:

```
D[F[Cos[x]+2], x]
___
-Sin[x] Derivative[1][F][Cos[x]+2]

Tan[x]=Sin[x]/Cos[x]
```

changes the equation to

```
F'[y]=Sin[x]+1/Cos[x]
```

with

```
x = ArcCos[y - 2]

DSolve[F'[y] == Sin[ArcCos[y - 2]] + 1/Cos[ArcCos[y - 2]], F[y], y]
```

---

```
{{F[y] -> 
   1/2 (-2 + y) Sqrt[-3 + 4 y - y^2] - 1/2 ArcSin[2 - y] + C[1] + 
    Log[2 - y]}}
```

Use chain rule to get a new valid ODE and solve the ODE.

Comment: Please check your derivations for the 1st eq. You cannot cancel $e^x$ as you did--there is $e^{-x}$ on the rhs.

Comment: @yarchik. This is multiplicated to the left in front of the f[Exp[x]] to be identified as application of the chain rules of differentiation.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = {f'[E^x] == x*E^-x, f[1] == 0};
```

Let `y == E^x`, then for **real** `x`,  `x == Log[y]`

```
sol = DSolve[{f'[y] == Log[y]*E^(-Log[y]), f[1] == 0}, f, y][[1]]

(* {f -> Function[{y}, Log[y]^2/2]} *)
```

Verifying that `f` satisfies the original equation for **real** `x`

```
eqn /. sol // Simplify[#, Element[x, Reals]] &

(* {True, True} *)
```

Then `f[x]` is

```
f[x_] = f[x] /. sol

(* Log[x]^2/2 *)
```